# 5 BASIC MMAP RELATED QUERY

Tags: linux, mmap

Can you please help me understand below mentioned points w.r.t MMAP on LINUX:-

a) Why is it essential that the memory returned by either KMALLOC , DMA_ALLOC_COHERENT                                should be PAGE_ALLIGNED to be used for MMAP

b) krnl_area=(int *)((((unsigned long)krnl_ptr) + PAGE_SIZE - 1)&PAGE_MASK);
   Through some search I could figure out above code for the same,
   but I still not clear how it is done.

c) How do I confirm PAGE which I have done MMAP and then reserved so 
   that they aren't swapped using SetPageReserved , has being correctly done 
   by kernel .

i.e If I am doing an  SetPageReserved for say 4 PAGE which are MMAPEd, 
   how do I confirm it that the scheduler wont be swapping these pages as
   I have done  SetPageReserved on these pages.

d) Is there any function to UN_RESERVED the page, I tried  SetUnPageReserved 
   but could not figure out header file for this function

e) What is difference i.e which one among (1) & (2) is the correct way to 
   provide physical address in remap_pfn_range ...

(1)  (virt_to_phys((void *)krnl_ptr) >> PAGE_SHIFT)

```
     or
```

(2)  (vma->vm_pgoff)

Because I have seen sample code using either (1) or (2) but could not 
   understand if they both are same or different?
   If different when to use which form?

Answer (score 0):

For point (d) the solution to un-reserve the PAGE the correct function is ClearPageReserved(page)....

I am still trying to understand other points .Can any one please guide for the same

Ashish Mishra